# Autocovariance and autocorrelation function of AR(1) process

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, covariance, model, autoregressive

[image]

I'm preparing the exam about AR models, precisely I have this exercise which I have some issues with points "d" and "e".

My try was:
Knowing that $W_t=X_t-X_{t-1}$, $h=1$ so:

d) $\gamma\left(1\right)=Var\left(W_t\right)\cdot\phi^{\left|1\right|}$

$\rho\left(1\right)=\phi^{\left|1\right|}$

Is plausible this conclusion? Do you have other solutions to suggest?

about **e)**, could you give me some hints to solve this point?